# Can't seem to get a background image to fit full size (HTML,CSS)

Tags: html, css, menu, margin

I'm trying to work with a template and having some troubles. I changed the menu bar to different style but now I can't get rid of a grey space. I want the image to go full width. The code is a mess right now so I don't know what even to look at.
[image]
The question is how to get rid of that grey margin space. What could be the problem?

```css
 
nav {
  float: right;
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 0 15%, 80% 15%, 80% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  background: black;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 15%, 80% 15%, 80% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  z-index: 6;
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  width:min-content;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
}

ul li:nth-child(3)~li {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}

a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: inherit
}
/*===== HEADER HERO =====*/
.single_slider {
  position: relative;
  height: 800px;
  z-index: 5;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center; /* optional */
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
  .single_slider {
    height: 770px;
    
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .single_slider {
    height: 650px;
  }
}

.single_slider::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(57, 36, 36, 0.5);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.slider_content {
  padding-top: 80px;
}

.slider_content .title {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .slider_content .title {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .slider_content .title {
    font-size: 34px;
  }
}

.slider_content p {
  margin-top: 25px;
  color: #fff;
}

.slider_content .main-btn {
  margin-top: 45px;
}

.slider-active .slick-dots {
  position: absolute;
  right: 3%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .slider-active .slick-dots {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .slider-active .slick-dots li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
  }
}

.slider-active .slick-dots li button {
  width: 25px;
  height: 5px;
  background: none;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-radius: 1px;
  font-size: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
  border: 0;
}

.slider-active .slick-dots li.slick-active button {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 45px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
        <ul class="horizontal">
          <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li class="far fa-circle"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Review</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

        <div id="home" class="header_hero slider-active">
            <div class="single_slider bg_cover d-flex align-items-center" style="background-image: url(assets/images/slider/hh.jpg)">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-10 col-sm-11">
                            <div class="slider_content">
                                <h3 class="title" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="0.2s">Mind Blowing Photograpy Web Template</h3>
                                <p data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="0.6s">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod  invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
                                <a href="javscript:void(0)" class="main-btn main-btn-2" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="0.9s">Download Now</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[image: Seems to be one more layer of gray box under the picture]

Comment: We can't help you without any code snippets. Please make a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the image cover the whole background you can use [background-size: cover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size). I also noticed that your `nav` is behind your content, to fix this you could give it a higher `z-index` then the `single-slider`. You also need to set the `position` otherwise the `z-index` has no effect.

*PS: I replaced your background with a placeholder to show you it works.*

```css
nav {
  float: right;
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 0 15%, 80% 15%, 80% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  background: black;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 15%, 80% 15%, 80% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  z-index: 6;
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  width:min-content;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
}

ul li:nth-child(3)~li {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}

a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: inherit
}
/*===== HEADER HERO =====*/
.single_slider {
  position: relative;
  height: 800px;
  z-index: 5;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center; /* optional */
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
  .single_slider {
    height: 770px;
    
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .single_slider {
    height: 650px;
  }
}

.single_slider::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(57, 36, 36, 0.5);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="horizontal">
    <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="far fa-circle"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Review</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="home" class="header_hero slider-active">
  <div class="single_slider bg_cover d-flex align-items-center" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/500)">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-10 col-sm-11">
          <div class="slider_content">
            <h3 class="title" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="0.2s">Mind Blowing Photograpy Web Template</h3>
            <p data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="0.6s">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod  invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
            <a href="javscript:void(0)" class="main-btn main-btn-2" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="0.9s">Download Now</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but this might help:

```
img{
background-size: cover; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to get it with class ?

```
     .single_slider.bg_cover.d-flex.align-items-center {

     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: auto;
     }
```

Comment: Just tried it and there seems to be one more layer of gray box.

Answer (score 0):

You using background-image url in style in your code.

Have you try this code?

```
<div class="single_slider bg_cover d-flex align-items-center" style="background-image: url(assets/images/slider/hh.jpg);background-size: cover;">
```